# How to be sure variable names in comments get changed when refactoring in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, refactoring, comments

If I've got a comment that says something like "the property myCoolVar does this...", referring to a property called `myCoolVar`, and then I go and refactor->rename the property in Xcode, is there a way to automatically change all instances of the text `myCoolVar`, including comments?  Or do I just need to do a project-wide find/replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although refactor can reduce a lot of work, you should always be careful when using it. Refactor works in many cases but it's not perfect. For example, it won't change text in your comments and by changing the property `myCoolVar` you won't get the variable itself changed (`_myCoolVar`). So better take care if you are accessing the variable directly, for example in initializer, setter, and getter methods.

Find/replace will work but I suggest you to change "word by word" instead of "change all", because you may change another variables that contain the same word.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an IDE that considers comments when renaming variables. [JetBrains AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) does this.

If you want to stick with Xcode (and its mediocre refactor tools) you have to find/inspect/replace.